# Why IE render null if model not exist

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Why in IE 11 renders 'null' if my model not exist?
For example:

```
<tr>
    <td [innerHTML]="model?.prop1 | my-pipe"> </td>
</tr>
```

Imaginate: when the page is load, I sending request to the server and the result is json with `prop1` field and if server answer as 404 not found (or something else, the reason is not important) my model is null and IE 11 browser render the `NULL` into `td` tag, but FF and Chrome render empty into this tag.

P.S. I want to know the reason for this behavior. 
I know how to fix it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14241). It's being tracked as an Edge issue, according to [this comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14241#issuecomment-280801288). A fix for IE is highly unlikely, I'd even say out of the question.

For anyone who doesn't know how to fix it: the workaround in this case is to use `*ngIf`:

```
<td *ngIf="model?.prop1" [innerHTML]="model?.prop1 | my-pipe"> </td>
```

When the problem occurs with attributes, for example:

```
<textarea [value]="model?.prop1"></textarea>
```

Then you can use `attr.value` instead:

```
<textarea [attr.value]="model?.prop1"></textarea>
```